# Setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH for gegl library still didn't allow configure to proceed

Tags: software-installation, gimp

I'm installing GIMP 2.8 (I need that version in order to use a plugin not available with GIMP 2.10). There is one last library needed, it asks for gegl-0.2.

My system has gegl-0.3 so I set up the pck-config to look in the folder where the gegl-0.3.pc file is.

```
kim@kim-MS-7917:~/Downloads/gimp-2.8.22$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

returns

```
 /~/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

which is right.
However, running ./configure still ends with the error `No package 'gegl-0.2' found`

I found other gegl packages on Synaptic, and installed libgegl-dev but the problem remains the same.

The error indicates there may be another way around the problem

```
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GEGL_CFLAGS
and GEGL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Alright, so maybe I can change those environment variables and resolve this that way. But how do I set them to avoid the need to call pkg-config?

I went ahead and tried in the terminal `export VARNAME=GEGL_CFLAGS` and then `export VARNAME=GEGL_LIBS` and then ran `./configure` again. That didn't help.

Ok. I have now downloaded gegl-0.2.0.tar.bz2 with the idea maybe it really needs that version. But I really don't know. Clearly I'm just casting about here.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you need: `sudo apt-get install libgegl-dev`? BTW which plugin are you after?

Comment: @andrew.46 Yeah, I installed that too, shoulda mentioned it. It still gives me the same error. I need the Nvidia DDS plugin so I can produce a cubemap in the format needed for Unreal Engine 4. (Those create the illusion of an image on a sphere for backgrounds in the distance in 3d environments.)

Comment: Interestingly enough Gimp 2.10.10 has import and export to DDS files available by default. I believe that this is based on the plugin that worked with older releases of Gimp. Some details here: https://www.gimp.org/news/2019/04/07/gimp-2-10-10-released/ . Import and export of dds files worked perfectly here with no added plugin needed.

Comment: And this version of gimp has a PPA for 18.04: https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp?field.series_filter=bionic

Comment: @andrew.46 Look at that. I just found that before checking back here. I shouldn't have listened to what came up when I googled it.

Comment: The internet is filled with outdated information....